# how to loop map value by key

Tags: flutter, dart

i usually loop a `list<Map<String, dynamic>>` with `for(var item in list)` / `for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++)` for list like this. Usually i just call `for(var item in list2) item['value']`

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> list2 = [
    {
      'value': 'Value number one',
    },
    {
      'value': 'Value number two',
    },
  ];
```

but then i have a list that looks like this, since every item has different keys i cannot use this anymore `for(var item in list) item['value']`. How to loop and get all the value  ?

```
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> list = [
    {

      '1': {
        'value': 'Value number one',
      },

      '2': {
        'value': 'Value number two',
      },

    }
  ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dummyData` is a list of map  though it contains only a single map.

If you just want to get values from Map using key, you can get list of keys 1st. or `myMap.values.toList()`

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> myMap = {};
List<String> keys = myMap.keys.toList();
List<dynamic> values = myMap.values.toList();
```

For `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`

```dart
  List<String> dummyDataKeys = [];
  List<dynamic> dummyDataValues = [];
  for (final item in dummyData) {
    // dummyDataKeys = [
    //   ...dummyDataKeys,
    //   ...item.keys.toList(),
    // ];
    dummyDataKeys.addAll(item.keys.toList());
    dummyDataValues.addAll(item.values.toList());
  }
```

More about [`Map`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Map-class.html) and [`List`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/dart-core/List-class.html).

Comment: okayyy thankssss

Answer (score 0):

try this code is simple :

```
 for(var item in list){

    for(var item2 in item.values){
  
        print(item2['value']);

    } 
}
```